# new JSONObject() lead to ERROR if json starts with [] instead of {} in Java/windows 7?

Tags: java, json

Does Apache JSONObject() only support json that begin and end under curly braces? I'm getting the following error:

org.apache.commons.json.JSONException: Expecting '{' on line 1, column 2 instead, obtained token: 'Token: [

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the JSON format? [Here it is](http://json.org/). Review it.

Comment: `{}` is a JSON object, `[]` is a JSON array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it starts with a square bracket then it's not a JSON *object*, it's a JSON *array*.

Comment: According to Sun, "An object is a class instance or an array."

Comment: @user3388884 I mean in JSON terms, not Java terms - a JSON object is roughly equivalent to a Java `Map`, and a JSON array to a Java `List`.  I'm not familiar with this particular JSON library but every library I've used (gson, jackson, json.org, Grails) uses separate Java classes to represent JSON arrays and JSON objects, with a common superclass named something like JsonElement or JSONValue.